# Cursor Null Object reference Crashes with Camera Not Gallery

Tags: android, android-cursor, android-camera-intent

New on android and following this tutorial:

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-using-php-mysql-android-studio/#comment-12178

i am able to send a picture selected from gallery and some other edittext like name, address, etc. into a db. I added some code, to make it work also with a button that opens the camera, i can take the picture and save it, but when i try to send this information to the db, the app crashes.

I hope someone can help me, i've been strugling about it a while.

```
private Bitmap bitmap;
private Uri filePath;



 private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Elige una imagen"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == CAM_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ){
        Toast.makeText(TerminosYC.this.getActivity(), "si hay foto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 try {
 bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), (filePath));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

 }else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ) {
            filePath = data.getData();

            try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            areaLeyendaImagen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            areaFotoCargada.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imagencargada.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textoimagencargada.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            area_cerrarIagen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            cerrarImagen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            buttonChoose.setError(null);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


  public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
    document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    cursor.close();

    cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
    cursor.close();

    return path;
}

 public class CargarDatos extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        ////////////////-------------
        String correo = campo_correo.getText().toString().trim();
        String nombre = campo_nombre.getText().toString().trim();
        String apellido= campo_apellido.getText().toString().trim();
        String telefono= campo_telefono.getText().toString().trim();
        String categoria= customspinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
        String titulo = campo_titulo.getText().toString().trim();
        String descripcion = campo_descripcion.getText().toString().trim();
        String latitud = Double.toString(latitudeeeee);
        String longitud = Double.toString(longitudeeee);

        String s = (campo_publico.isChecked() ? "1" : "0");
        String r = (campo_terminos.isChecked() ? "1" : "0");

        //getting the actual path of the image
        String path = getPath(filePath);

        //Uploading code
        try {
            String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            //Creating a multi part request
            new MultipartUploadRequest(TerminosYC.this.getActivity(), uploadId, Constants.UPLOAD_URL)
                    .addFileToUpload(path, "image") //Adding file
                    .addParameter("name",correo) //Adding text parameter to the request
                    .addParameter("nombre",nombre)
                    .addParameter("apellido",apellido)
                    .addParameter("telefono", telefono)
                    .addParameter("categoria", categoria)
                    .addParameter("titulo", titulo)
                    .addParameter("descripcion", descripcion)
                    .addParameter("publico", s)
                    .addParameter("terminos", r)
                    .addParameter("latitud",latitud)
                    .addParameter("longitud",longitud)
                    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                    .setMaxRetries(2)
                    .startUpload(); //Starting the upload

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            Toast.makeText(TerminosYC.this.getActivity(), exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
        }
    }


class btnTakePhotoClicker implements  Button.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //////////////////////////////
        //Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        filePath = Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, filePath);

        startActivityForResult(intent, CAM_REQUEST);
 }
}
```

I get the following erros:

```
08-16 12:58:48.770 7403-7403/com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta, PID: 7403
                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta.TerminosYC.getPath(TerminosYC.java:553)
                                                                                      at com.example.lupitagarcia.yosoyvallarta.TerminosYC$1.onClick(TerminosYC.java:352)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5721)
                                                                                      at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10936)
                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22620)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

UPDATE:
I've realized when taking the picture using the camera on the app, this is not shown on the gallery inmediatly, i need to restart my phone in order to see the pictures on the folder created. I don't know if this might have something to do my problem.

Comment: the [`query`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String)) method can return null. There is probably an error in your URI. can you post the URI you are trying to access?

Comment: I already updated the information @litelite

Comment: But did you use a debugger to make sure there was actually something in there?

Comment: when debuging it i get : file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Vallarta%20en%20tus%20manos%20Nougat/IMG_20170816_132423.jpg